# line break in TEXT field in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a field there is an hidden line break with 
, for example

```
select pd.title_eng from product p join product_desc pd on p.pid=pd.pid where pd.desc_eng = '
\n';
```

the above sql statement won't recognize \n as a line break character, how to select it out?

thanks

Comment: is the line break the only content of *pd.desc_eng* our you trying to check if the field contains a line break? otherwise you should use LIKE '%\n%' instead of =

Answer (score 0):

No, MySQL should recognize '\n' as newline, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html

But please note, in your example, there is a newline literally before the \n which is a proper representation of a newline.
Maybe you want to use the like operator?

```
select pd.title_eng 
from product p 
   join product_desc pd on p.pid=pd.pid 
where pd.desc_eng like '%\n%';
```